# Java BigInteger mod 1000000007

Tags: java, biginteger, fibonacci

So I wrote java code that can find N'th Fibonacci number. My problem is, I have to output the answer % 1000000007. I thought I could simply do it by writing

```
System.out.println(answer.mod(1000000007));
```

But it doesn't allow me to do that, and I get an error "The method mod(BigInteger) in the type BigInteger is not applicable for the arguments (int)"

Can someone please help me, here's my code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class dmoj
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       BigDecimal d, v, t, a;
       BigInteger  b;
       int index;

       int n = scan.nextInt();

       double phi1 = (1 + Math.sqrt(5)) / 2;
       double phi2 = (1 - Math.sqrt(5)) / 2;    
       double sqrt = Math.sqrt(5);

       d = new BigDecimal(phi1);
       v = new BigDecimal(phi2);
       a = new BigDecimal(sqrt);

       d = d.pow(n);
       v = v.pow(n);
       t = d.subtract(v);
       t = t.divide(a);

       b = t.toBigInteger();

       System.out.println(b.mod(1000000007)); //I get an error here.
   }
}
```

Comment: What is unclear about the error message?

Comment: Did you read the error message? You're passing an `int` to a method that expects a `BigInteger`.

Comment: How can I fix it, I tried everything.

Comment: If you tried everything and nothing worked, there's no way to fix it.

Comment: I agree -- you clearly didn't try everything, and the SO community strictly refuses to talk to anyone who lies so outrageously...

Answer (score 6):

You have to pass it another `BigInteger:

```
System.out.println(answer.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(1000000007)));
```

Comment: Or, you could instantiate the big integer with a string: `b.mod(new BigInteger("1000000007"))`. Though I prefer @Todd's code as long as the number on the right can be fitted into a `Long`, otherwise the string version is necessary.